# Jquery accordion and inner animation e.stopPropagation(); issues

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a simple accordion animated by jQuery and inside one of the options I'm doing a CSS animated iPhone button (on/off). The problem is that every time I click on the button the accordion jQuery (I'm pretty sure there are some issues with either the `e.stopPropagation();` or `e.preventDefault();`) avoid the button to animate, I'm sure of this because I have take off the accordion script and the button works fine, I'm pretty new with jQuery so I really don't know how to handle the problem.

Just a note when I take off the `e.preventDefault();` line from the accordion script just the first button animate and every time I click another one it animates the first one, is a bit crazy.

Here's the online example:
http://wearehellyeah.com/test/nueva_tipologia_12.html#

Here's the script for the accordion:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $(".acordeon ul li:has(ul)").addClass("has-sub");

    $('.acordeon').on("click", "li", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.acordeon').on("click", ".has-sub", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown('normal');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).children("ul").slideUp('normal');
        }
    });
```

The html for the iPhone button within the accordion:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
<div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about removing the stopPropagation commands?

Comment: If i do that when i click on the button within the accordeon the accordeon closes, so not working

Comment: Then set the stopPropagation for the switches' event functions?

Comment: If i do this just the first button animates and when i click another one it animates always the first one

$('.boton-revista').on("click", ".onoffswitch-switch", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});